# Как оптимизировать сайт в таком случае?

Tags: оптимизация-сайтов

Есть сайт на WooCommerce, интернет-магазин. Тестирую через GTmetrix.
Вес главной страницы сайта, где больше всего контента — 5 МБ. Все изображения оптимизированы. Время полной загрузки страницы — 9 секунд. Количество запросов — 161. Количество запросов достигло 161 из-за:

1. Метрики
2. Подключения онлайн-чата Envybox

Я понимаю, что 9 секунд требуется из-за того, что сайт считается полностью загруженным когда получит все запросы. Можно ли как-то улучшить производительность?

Недавно был еще один заказчик. У него сайт на WordPress загружает много стороннего. У него количество запросов порядка 220, полная загрузка страницы согласно GTmetrix составляет 20 секунд, вес тоже небольшой. Вопрос: если действительно все, что там есть — нужное, сайт, метрики, аналитики, и т.п, и они от этого не хотят отказываться — а все что можно оптимизировать уже оптимизировал, то каким образом можно улучшить статистику?

Answer (score 0):

1. На вордпресс обязательно ставьте кэширующий плагин (на свой вкус).
2. Крайне желательно на передний план поставить nginx, у которого включить сжатие статических ресурсов (js, html, css), выставить время кэширования у клиента, как минимум на неделю.
3. ssl сертификат + протокол http2 (все настраивается в том-же nginx) - позволит грузить все локальные ресурсы практически одновременно
4. Все изображения пережать, например https://tinypng.com/ (есть плагины для wp)

С внешними ресурсами врядли что-то можно сделать. Разве что разместить в самом низу страницы